# Trouble using the `at` command on mac

Tags: macos, at-job

I'm unable to get the `at` command to run from the Mac Terminal.

I've tried `at -f test.txt 10:44` which puts it in the queue, but then it never runs.

I've tried `sh test.txt | at 10:43` which puts it in the queue (though it never runs), but it also runs the script immediately.

Just running `sh test.txt` runs fine, it is a test script to send an email.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the answer may be in the man page. `man at`, *IMPLEMENTATION NOTES
     Note that at is implemented through the launchd(8) daemon periodically invoking atrun(8), which is disabled by default.  See atrun(8) for information about enabling atrun.*

Comment: @JustinWood You're absolutely correct. Here's a link I found which shows how to load the job. If you want to make an answer, I'll check it: http://superuser.com/questions/43678/mac-os-x-at-command-not-working

Answer (score 0):

> I think the answer may be in the man page. man at, IMPLEMENTATION
>   NOTES Note that at is implemented through the launchd(8) daemon
>   periodically invoking atrun(8), which is disabled by default. See
>   atrun(8) for information about enabling atrun.

This is from the comment by Justin Wood.

I thank him for his help - I should have read the man page more closely.

Comment: I asked him to, as you can see in the comments above.